# Google Maps marker shown in the wrong place

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to show some points/coordinates retrieved from an SQLite databse. The weird thing that when I launch map activity I have the marker shown on a strange place, in the sea, near to Gabon and Nigeria: http://imageshack.us/f/402/gabond.png/

I tried to set manually the map to be centered on a given coordinates and always the same problem. One other thing, I have this logcat error when launching the activity:

```
08-21 13:19:59.326: ERROR/MapActivity(404): Couldn't get connection factory client
```

Code:

```
CoordBD CoordBd = new CoordBD(this);
        CoordBd.open();

        Coordo coordo = new Coordo(36.876673,10.325928);
        Coordo coordo2 = new Coordo(36.876982,10.326228);
        //CoordBd.open();
        CoordBd.insertCoordo(coordo);
        CoordBd.insertCoordo(coordo2);
        // CoordBd.close();

        maMap = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.myGmap);
        maMap.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        ItemizedOverlayPerso pinOverlay = new ItemizedOverlayPerso(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker));

        /*db = openOrCreateDatabase(
            "coord.bd"
            , SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY
            , null
            );
        db.setVersion(1);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        db.setLockingEnabled(true);*/

        String[] result_columns = new String[] {COL_LATI, COL_LONGI};
        Cursor cur = db.query(true, TABLE_COORD, result_columns,
        null, null, null, null, null, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
            int latitude = cur.getColumnIndex("latitude");
            int longitude = cur.getColumnIndex("longitude");
            point = new GeoPoint(microdegrees(latitude),microdegrees(longitude));
            pinOverlay.addPoint(point);
            cur.moveToNext();
        }
        cur.close();
        CoordBd.close();

        maMap.getOverlays().add(pinOverlay);
        monControler = maMap.getController();
        monControler.setZoom(12);
        monControler.setCenter(point);

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 500.0f, this);
```

What could be the source of the problem?
PS: I have the same problem when installing the app on the phone.
Thank you for your help.
**EDIT: Logcat:** (after modifying it with hooked answer):

```
08-22 01:55:35.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-22 01:55:35.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{carburant.android.com/carburant.android.com.Geo}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
08-22 01:55:35.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
08-22 01:55:35.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
08-22 01:55:35.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
08-22 01:55:35.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
08-22 01:55:35.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 01:55:35.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-22 01:55:35.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-22 01:55:35.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 01:55:35.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-22 01:55:35.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-22 01:55:35.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-22 01:55:35.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 01:55:35.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
08-22 01:55:35.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getDouble_native(Native Method)
08-22 01:55:35.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getDouble(CursorWindow.java:399)
08-22 01:55:35.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getDouble(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:138)
08-22 01:55:35.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253):     at carburant.android.com.Geo.onCreate(Geo.java:92)
08-22 01:55:35.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-22 01:55:35.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
08-22 01:55:35.402: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(253):     ... 11 more

EDIT: Added class creating the DB:

public class MaBaseSQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String CREATE_BDD = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_COORD + " ("
    + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_LATI + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
    + COL_LONGI + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    MaBaseSQLite(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //on créé la table à partir de la requête écrite dans la variable CREATE_BDD
        db.execSQL(CREATE_BDD);
    }
```

Comment: The reason you are getting that point there is because you co-ordinates are being set to 0,0, which in the picture supplied, that is the 0,0 point on the earth.  I'll look at the code to see if I can find the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a breakpoint in your while loop and you'll probably notice that latitude and longitude are both 0, or 0 and 1.  The problem is with the following two lines.  You're getting the column index, not actual values.  You'll also want to store your co-ordinates as doubles rather than integers:

```
int latitude = cur.getColumnIndex("latitude");
int longitude = cur.getColumnIndex("longitude");
```

try setting it to:

```
double latitude = cur.getDouble(cur.getColumnIndex("latitude"));
double longitude = cur.getDouble(cur.getColumnIndex("longitude"));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.I'm using now this code snippet instead of the old one and i'm getting a FC. Please see my edited post.

Comment: What's that error ? `get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed`

Comment: The error in your stack trace is saying that the column name you're trying to access is not available in the cursor.  You'll need to post the table creation code so that we can see your column names, as well as the code that returns your cursor object.  Also, try getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_NAME) to get a better error message.

Comment: I'm using now `getColumnIndexOrThrow` and having this logcat error:`08-22 02:08:27.192: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'latitude' does not exist
`.How it does not exist :\. I'll post the code to create the DB.

Comment: The added info doesn't provide much. You'll need to post the code used to create your TABLE_COORD in the DB (CREATE TABLE COORD.....), and please provide the values of both COL_LATI and COL_LONGI.

Comment: Dude, i solved the problem, i named by columns with "Latitude" and "Longitude" capital L ;). Finally :). Thank you very much dude.